# Combinatorics Question Olympiad Prep

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I came across this question in my textbook. They have strictly instructed to use combinatorial methods to solve it.

$\tan nA = \frac{{\binom{n}{1}t - \binom{n}{3}t^3 + \binom{n}{5}t^5 - \ldots}}{{1 - \binom{n}{2}t^2 + \binom{n}{4}t^4 - \ldots}}$

where $t = \tan A.$

Comment: Please write the problem in the question using mathjax

Comment: You can look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for a MathJax tutorial. Images are not well received on here, because their content is not searchable.

Comment: Done! Is it fine now?

Comment: Is $n$ allowed to be a natural number, an integer, or a real number.

Comment: It's not given in the question. However, taking in consideration the level of this textbook it is most likely a natural number

Comment: I'm not sure what a purely combinatorial approach would mean, as you somehow need to use properties of the tangent function, but a reasonable approach might be to let $z=1+ti$, and use the fact that the ratio of the immaginary to real parts of $z^n$ will be $\tan(nA)$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more? I am essentially just a high school student with limit knowledge. I have just started with this elementary introduction to combinatorics and pre college math in general

Comment: You've written an expression that takes a ratio of two infinite series.  So if you are saying your "elementary introduction" doesn't cover a power series expansion for $\tan x$, then you need to step back and ask some threshold questions about what the expression you wrote means.